# How were Miller or Mann able to send information from their planet but Romilly couldn't send observations on the black hole?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

When Cooper, Brand, and Doyle go to Miller's planet in *Interstellar*, Romilly stays behind to study the black hole.

After their arrival, Romilly says that he tried to send information to Prof. Brand but nothing goes out only information (messages) comes in.

But they at first decide to go to these three planets (Edmund's, Miller's and Mann's) because they received signals from these planets when they were on Earth.

How can they receive messages from Earth from near a black hole but cannot send messages to Earth from near a black hole?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How was the data transferred across galaxies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27337/how-was-the-data-transferred-across-galaxies)

Comment: No. please read question properly. it's not about how data were transfers between two galaxies.
the question is about Romilly not able to send his observation(study) on black hole to Earth but the probes were able to send signal to earth indicating presence of suitable atmosphere for life.

Comment: @YogeshGupta but that is about how they're sending the data across galaxies

Comment: They were able to send data from planets(Edmund's, Miller's, Mann's) across galaxies to Earth but Romilly is not able to send his studies on Gargantua.